# Tableau - creating bands

Tags: tableau-api

could someone suggest/guide how to achieve this in Tableau (Desktop):
Q)classify the entire data into 4 parts:
  i)High Sales - Low Distribution Costs
  i)High Sales - High Distribution Costs
  i)Low Sales- Low Distribution Costs
  i)Low Sales- High Distribution Costs
I have [Rx Dollars], [Distribution Costs] as fields along with other fields

Thanks in Advance
~Shabbir

Comment: I tried using clusters, but unable to define them

Answer (score 1):

Try an IF statement in a calculated field.

1.Create Calculated Field: *Analysis->Create Calculated Field*

2.Name it and enter a formula like this:

`IF (put calculation logic here) THEN "High Sales - Low Distribution Costs"
ELSEIF (put calculation logic here) THEN "High Sales - High Distribution Costs"
ELSEIF (put calculation logic here) THEN "Low Sales- Low Distribution Costs"
ELSEIF (put calculation logic here) THEN "Low Sales- High Distribution Costs"}
ELSE "Other"
END`

3.Then pull the new dimension pill into the rows.

Cant really help you with the calculation as your question/possible logic of the bands is not clear enough.

Comment: Hi, i tried this but no help: if sum([Rx Dollars])>AVG([Rx Dollars]) and
sum([Distribution Costs])>avg([Distribution Costs])
then "High Sales-High Distribution Cost"
elseif sum([Rx Dollars])>AVG([Rx Dollars]) and
sum([Distribution Costs])<avg([Distribution Costs])
then "High Sales-Low Distribution Cost"
elseif sum([Rx Dollars])<AVG([Rx Dollars]) and
sum([Distribution Costs])<avg([Distribution Costs])
then "Low Sales-Low Distribution Cost"
else "Low Sales-High Distribution Cost"
END